# jquery recognize if li is clicked or p inside the li is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dhtml

```
<ul id='myid'>  
<li id='1'> my text 1 <p id='1' >inside p1 clicked</p></li>  
<li id='2'> my text 2 <p id='1' >inside p2 clicked</p></li>  
<li id='3'> my text 3 <p id='1' >inside p3 clicked</p></li>  
<li id='4'> my text 4 <p id='1' >inside p4 clicked</p></li>  
<li id='5'> my text 5 <p id='1' >inside p5 clicked</p></li>  

</ul>
```

Hi , I just want to know how to alert if I click on "my text 1" and how to alert if I click on "inside p1 clicked"  . Because whenever I try to click on "my text1" it's working. but when I try to click on "inside p1 clicked" its bringing two alerts one with the "my text 1" and other with the "inside p1 clicked". Please help what could be the solution.

below is the code which I m using.

$("#myid").delegate('p','click', function(){

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post your jquery code also?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its a matter of [**event bubbling**](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-flow-bubbling). You can get the current clicked element using `event.target`.

If you want to stop event bubbling you can use [`event.stopPropagation`](http://docs.jquery.com/Types/Event#event.stopPropagation.28.29)

```
// click event for li
$("#myid li").click(function(){
    alert("li clicked");
});

// click event for p
$("#myid li p").click(function(e){
    alert("p clicked");
    // stop event bubbling
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

And you HTML is also not valid. Never start an id with a numeric.

If you want to attach click event for future elements also then use `.live` or `.delegate`.

And put `return false` instead of `e.stopPropagation`.

```
// click event for li
$("#myid li").live("click", function(){
    alert("li clicked");
});

// click event for p
$("#myid li p").live("click", function(){
    alert("p clicked");
    // stop event bubbling
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks Mr. Rahul, but I don't know what will be the code. Can you give me some working code for the same ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a selector like

$("li p").click(function(){
alert("p inside li is clicked");
})

here is the [Demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net/kjjZw/)

Comment: Thanks Vaibhav,  I have two alerts one is with the li and other one is with the inside the li it's with the <p>  can you give me the demo for the same.

Answer (score 1):

If you're already getting two events, calling `event.stopPropagation()` in each click handler will prevent the other from being called.

Even simpler would be to add one click handler to #myid and then check the event.target property to decide how to handle it.